# How to upload file in headless browser using robot class in selenium java

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver, headless-browser

How to upload file in headless browser using robot class in selenium java as sendkeys() method not working in my case. I am using firefox and selenium web driver java for my script

Comment: Is it necessary to upload file using `robot class`? Have you try with `AutoIT`?

Comment: Not necessary Please let me know how to upload using AutoIT

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void setClipboardData(String string) {
    StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(string);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection,null);
}          

setClipboardData(path);
//native key strokes for CTRL, V and ENTER keys

Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

**Note:** If you are using headless browsers such as chrome or phantomjs, robot class will take the control of present window and send path in it. Also if you use autoIT, script will be waiting for the active window to be appear. so obviously script will be paused and it fails to find the next element.

---

AutoIT script

```
WinWaitActive("Open")
Send(@ScriptDir & "\logo.png")
Send("{ENTER}")
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use Robot class for uploading file using selenium java.
Just at first, (1) Upload your files in /tmp folder in case of linux and temp folder in case of windows OS and then, use below code to upload files

```
String path = FILE_UPLOAD_PATH; 
//(Full path with file name from /tmp folder)
driver.findElement(By.id("FILE_INPUT_ID")).sendKeys(path);
```

and it will upload file.

**Note** : Please remove file from /tmp folder after uploading, if no need to free memory.